# Primary key request in MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, web

I used this code however it showed that unrecognized alter operation and also that key is unrecognized.

```
ALTER TABLE `ecommerce`.`users` (id INT(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY-KEY AUTO_INCREMENT);
```

Comment: Look at MODIFY in [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html), maybe it helps

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE ecommerce.users add column id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b69bf67c3a9507864049500b39474d85) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

I realize the OP might already have the column and want to replace the definition.  That works with this syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE users modify column id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b2d09df3c310877ca6033b8c33112e14) is this db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

you can give primary while creating your table or after create table you can add primary key by alter table

while creating table

```
create table info(id int primary key,Name varchar(25),dept varchar(25));
create table info(id int,Name varchar(25),dept varchar(25),primary key(id));
```

after creating table

```
alter table info add primary key(id);
```

Comment: Please check your spelling. Consider testing code before posting.